# How to add bootstrap css to my Wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

I am developing a Wordpress plugin.

I would like to know how to integrate a Bootstrap CSS file into my plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a function in your Plugin file

```
function add_scripts_and_css(){
  wp_enqueue_style('your-plugin-bootrtrap_css',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'folderpath/bootstrap.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts_and_css');
```

This is the way to add `wp_enqueue_style` to add css files and `wp_enqueue_script` to add JavaScript `.js` files.

Comment: You have missed a `'` in your code. It is `. 'folderpath/bootstrap.css');` instead … Please update your answer.

Comment: Thank you for notifying me on my mistake I edited my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
// load your plugin css into the website's front-end
function myplugin_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myplugin-style', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )."css/bootstrap.css" ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_enqueue_style' );
```

Add above code in your plugin `register_activation_hook`.